# What is the best ways to get the multiple checkbox checked value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

```
<div class="myBox">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Banana" value = "Banana" />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Orange" value = "Orange" />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Apple" value = "Apple" />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Papaya" value = "Papaya" />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Watermelon" value = "Watermelon" />
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "Grape" value = "Grape" />
</div>

<div id="display">
</div>
```

How to store it into array and display all the check-box checked value into the "#display" div immediately when someone is checked the check-box and also remove the value when someone is unchecked the check-box. For example, When I click on Banana then the "#display" div will display Banana and I continue to click on Grape then it will display Banana, Grape. Remove the word "Banana" from the "#display" div when unchecked the check-box so the "#display" div will only display "Grape". In Jquery.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `map()` function to get the checked values... and `join()` to join the array with `,`.

try this

```
$('.myBox  input:checkbox').change(function(){
  var tempValue='';
  tempValue=$('.myBox  input:checkbox').map(function(n){
      if(this.checked){
            return  this.value;
          };
   }).get().join(',');

   $('#display').html(tempValue);
})
```

OR

simple way

```
 $('.myBox  input:checkbox').change(function(){
  var tempValue='';
tempValue=$('.myBox  input:checkbox:checked').map(function(n){  //map all the checked value to tempValue with `,` seperated
            return  this.value;
   }).get().join(',');

   $('#display').html(tempValue);
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qg8JG/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this :

```
$(".myBox").on("change", "[type=checkbox]", function () {
    var s = "";
    $(".myBox [type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        s += this.value + ",";
    });
    $("#display").html(s.slice(0, s.length -1));
});
```

Everytime a `change` happens in the text box, `each` event gets the values of `checked` checkboxes and adds them to the `div`.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/cqZcX/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myBox").on("change", "[type=checkbox]", function () {
    var s = "";
    $(".myBox [type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        s += (s == '') ? this.value : "," + this.value;
    });
    $("#display").html(s);
});
```