# I want to alert values of radio button checked from function on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dynamic radio buttons in my form. I want to fetch their values in function. I use jquery code but it gives me only first selected radio button value

```
 This is my code of radio button
 <input type="radio" name="data[<?php print '.$x.';?>]" value="' . $student . '" />&nbsp;<label for name=' . $student . '>' . $student . '</label>
                            </label>



function form_values()
{

var a =  $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
alert(a);
}
```

Please, help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best ways to get the multiple checkbox checked value using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901255/what-is-the-best-ways-to-get-the-multiple-checkbox-checked-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make loop for each radio button and then alert value like below.

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){ 
        alert($(this).val();
    });
```

Comment: @Ronny Yes you can. Replace thiis alert($(this).val()); I have forgot to add ending comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function() { // On submit
   $(this).find("input[type="radio"]:checked").each(function(){ 
      alert($(this).val();
   });
});
```

`$(this).find("input")` only children are on the current form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have included html example also along with jquery.

```
<form method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="radio" name="first" value="YES" checked />YES&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="first" value="NO" />NO<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="second" value="YES" checked />YES&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="second" value="NO" />NO<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="third" value="YES" checked />YES&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="third" value="NO" />NO<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="fourth" value="YES" checked />YES&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="fourth" value="NO" />NO<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
NOTE: DO NOT FORGET TO INCLUDE JQUERY LIBRARY.
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    var r = new Array();
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){ 
        r.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(r); //////// You will get the values in r
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method for looping checked radio buttons

```
var chk = [];
$(':radio:checked').each(function(){
      //alert($(this).val());
       chk.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(chk);
```